# Cannot change gemset by rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemset

**Cannot change any gemset by rvm on macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287)**

**Default gemset is always selected no matter what I change to other gemset**

`rvm --version`

rvm 1.29.10 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]

`rvm list`

```
=* ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

`ruby -v`

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin19]

`cat ~/.profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

`rvm gemsset list`

```
gemsets for ruby-2.3.1 (found in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1)
=> (default)
   global
   gemset1
   gemset2
```

`rvm gemset use gemset1`

**Using ruby-2.3.1 with gemset default**

Or `rvm gemset use ruby-2.3.1@gemset1`

**Using ruby-2.3.1 with gemset default**

`echo $PATH`

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin
```

`echo $GEM_HOME`

/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1

`echo $GEM_PATH`

/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1

`gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin
     - /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
     - /Users/username/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin
```

`which rake`

/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake

Special thanks for anyone can help me on this case!

Answer (score 1):

Try either using `rvm gemset use gemset1` or `rvm use ruby-2.3.1@gemset1`.